New OPNsense setup, almost all default, 1111&8888 DNS set but can only access few sites?
So, I have a protectli box with opnsense 23.7.5 installed, currently I have the ISP router/modem in front of the opnsense box and a laptop (which I have been dual booting between win/lin) to try to get things setup.
I am able to access sites like google.com, cloudflare, but also bing, facebook, and apparently opnsense.org via the linux laptop I have connected but that is about it - other sites like wikipedia.org or reddit.com (pretty much any other site) just give me a "cant connect to server" error. In Win I can't even access the local opnsense box - it just times out and tells me 192.168.1.1 took too long to respond.
I can not ping 1.1.1.1 from the opnsense console nor from the computer I have connected to opnsense, it just tells me no route to host and 100% packet loss - so its been mentioned to me its not DNS?
I have tried ticking so many boxes and have reset back to defaults so many times that starting to feel like pulling my hair out over this and can't figure what I am doing wrong, I am so hoping to just get the most basic setup going (access websites) and then back that up so I can try to figure the other things out.
Please. Please help - I will post whatever log info is needed but I didn't want to just willy nilly post useless info so please let me know and I will happily post it.

anyone? Please?

In other words, you're able to access IPv6-capable sites only? Start with the basics – not websites (as that involves like five different things at once), but the individual parts one by one, e.g. if you suspect DNS, then are you able to make just DNS queries using nslookup or dig? If you get "no route" then does the laptop in fact have a default route via Opnsense, and does Opnsense have a default route via ISP or something?

Thanks, sorry for the belated reply no time to try to work on this as of late. So I tried nslookup and dig and didn't get a "no route" error https://pastebin.com/NygQH1Te though I am not sure what it means. Strangely I am able to access pastebin as well. This is driving me nuts - I can set up a linux box but am clueless with networking...

Also, i am often not even able to access opnsense, that is trying https://192.168.1.1 and it just times out? I thought I'd see what was showing up as the gateway but when i tried ifconfig -a I got https://pastebin.com/weJ9PfRx

You need to specify an actual domain name to query and only then (optionally) the server address to use, e.g. nslookup www.google.com 1.1.1.1 or dig superuser.com @1.1.1.1. Right now it's not giving useful results because it's treating the "1.1.1.1" as the domain name but querying the local system's DNS cache (and that most likely talks to a DNS server over IPv6).

ifconfig will not show gateways (though better to use ip addr instead, as Linux's version of ifconfig doesn't know how to show some things it should show) – gateways are the "default route" or "0.0.0.0/0 route" under ip route (or under netstat -rn but again 'ip route' is more reliable). This does already show however that you have IPv6 on your network – and I'm guessing that currently goes through your ISP-provided router as the gateway? – so yes, you're able to access IPv6-capable sites and it's only IPv4 that is broken.

@grawity_u1686, thank you so much for continuing to help. So I reposted nslookup/dig output (done correctly this time, thanks!) here www.pastebin.com/Mye9Q2Fp so ipv6 worx, ipv4 doesn't, do you know of any other tests I might run to further narrow down as to why ipv4 is not working?

Check whether the system has Opnsense as its IPv4 gateway; if it does, then check what the Opnsense firewall rules allow... While at it, also check whether the IPv6 gateway is Opnsense or something else – this all makes me suspect that Opnsense isn't actually between the modem and the laptop and you have a sort of "triangular" setup?

btw, github is telling me "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" I'd be happy (grateful) to do so if your ok with that

Anyway, I ran (on my laptop, should I be running these from an opnsense term?) netstat and ip route and got pastebin.com/35M6Z8nM i thought netstat would indicate the default but no? Is it possible to check the ipv4/6 gateway and firewall via the opnsense box directly (ie terminal rather than web gui as i can't access the webgui)

As for setup, I dont think so? wifi is def off/disconnected on this laptop, the laptop is physically connected to an ethernet adapter which has an ethernet cable going to the opnsense box, and another ethernet cable going from the opnsense box to the ISP router/modem or is the phys part of it not relevant?
